# Symfony crawler returns data with CR LF in windows but not in linux

Tags: php, symfony, web-crawler, newline, domcrawler

I'm trying to get data from  tags on a website by using the symfony crawler link this.

```
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $response = $this->client->get($url, [
            'http_errors' => false,
    ]);

    $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $crawler = new crawler($body);
    $version = $crawler->filter('tr > td');

    $i = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (something) {
            break;
        }
        $tableVersions[$table] = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $version->eq($i + 1)->text());
        $i++;
    }
}
return $tableVersions;
```

In windows this works, the preg_split nicely splits the words that i wanted to split and put them each separately in an array.
When i print out `$version->eq($i + 1)->text()` in windows it looks like this:

```
word1
word2
word3
```

In linux it just puts all the strings without any delimiter in the first element of the array like this.

```
word1word2word3
```

it's the exact same code.
So i'm guessing in windows the crawler returns new line feeds and in linux it doesn't? How should i then get a nice array of all the  tags on a html page and then filter them?

Comment: how are you "printing out" that value? what is the content of $version->eq($i + 1)->text() ?

Comment: As from somewhere in my brain: Linux and Windows treat `Line Breaks` differently. Maybe this gives you a direction to search further.

Comment: @KasiaGogolek i just echo it and watch it in my cli. And the content of  $version->eq($i + 1)->text() is just a long string that in my windows cli does a newline per word but doesn't in my Linux.

Comment: have you tried  the `PHP_EOL` constant instead of the other stuff? `PHP_EOL` holds the os-specific line break stuff so it would probably be correct on windows and linux.